# How can I recover oracle database without new data?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I have oracledb 11g. I setup archivelog mode on my server. There's my backup\recovery scenario:

```
rman TARGET SYS/pass@XE
RMAN> backup database plus archivelog;
```

After that I make changes to the data tables. Create new customer as example.
After that I execute in rman:

```
shutdown immediate;
startup mount;
restore database;
recover database; 
alter database open;
```

My server is started. I run my application and creater customer is there... Where's my mistake? I tried delete all dbf from db folder. And after restore database I saw my new customer. How can I restore a database without the data that was added to the database after the backup?

Comment: you need to perform a point-in-time recovery by specify the exact date and time, otherwise it will reapply all the archive logs available after the restore.

Comment: example here https://ss64.com/ora/rman_pitr_example.html